# Only show featured image on first page of paginated posts

Tags: posts, pagination

I'm experimenting with paginated posts on my site using the SmartMag theme, and I've customized my post content template quite a bit.

However, I still have one issue I'd like to fix: On paginated posts, the subsequent pages all show the featured image at the top. Is there a function that is theme agnostic which would only allow the featured image to show on the first page of a paginated post?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `is_paged()` for this. This function determines whether the query is for a paged result and not for the first page. So ofcourse, in your case, you should use `!is_paged()`.

Check out the docs here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_paged/

Comment: That makes sense, so in the section where I'm showing the featured image on the post, I would just wrap it in ```if(!is_paged()){//show image}```

Comment: I/m using this ```if (isset($props['featured_in_head'])) {
  if ( !is_paged() ){
 $props['featured'] = $props['featured_in_head'];
  }
}``` but it's not working. I just read that this won't work on posts that are split with <!--nextpage-->